# RabbitMq: no message converter found error while working with RPC using Grails Native RabbitMq plugin

Tags: java, grails, rabbitmq

I am using RabbitMq RPC style message. i write code for consumer as well as for producer but when i returning an object which is type of File from consumer side it will through an exception says:-

```
[ERROR] [rabbitmq.consumer.ConsumerContextImpl] unexpected exception class com.budjb.rabbitmq.exception.MessageConvertException encountered while responding from an RPC call with handler TaskConsumer
com.budjb.rabbitmq.exception.MessageConvertException: no message converter found to convert class ${source.getClass().name} to a byte array
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:526)
    at org.springsource.loaded.ri.ReflectiveInterceptor.jlrConstructorNewInstance(ReflectiveInterceptor.java:1002)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.CachedConstructor.invoke(CachedConstructor.java:77)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.ConstructorSite$ConstructorSiteNoUnwrapNoCoerce.callConstructor(ConstructorSite.java:102)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.callConstructor(AbstractCallSite.java:190)
    at com.budjb.rabbitmq.converter.MessageConverterManagerImpl.convertToBytes(MessageConverterManagerImpl.groovy:165)
    at com.budjb.rabbitmq.converter.MessageConverterManager$convertToBytes$1.call(Unknown Source)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCall(CallSiteArray.java:45)
    at com.budjb.rabbitmq.converter.MessageConverterManager$convertToBytes$1.call(Unknown Source)
    at com.budjb.rabbitmq.publisher.RabbitMessagePublisherImpl.convertMessageToBytes(RabbitMessagePublisherImpl.groovy:133)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.springsource.loaded.ri.ReflectiveInterceptor.jlrMethodInvoke(ReflectiveInterceptor.java:1270)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PogoMetaMethodSite$PogoCachedMethodSiteNoUnwrapNoCoerce.invoke(PogoMetaMethodSite.java:272)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PogoMetaMethodSite.callCurrent(PogoMetaMethodSite.java:52)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.callCurrent(AbstractCallSite.java:141)
    at com.budjb.rabbitmq.publisher.RabbitMessagePublisherImpl.send(RabbitMessagePublisherImpl.groovy:65)
    at com.budjb.rabbitmq.publisher.RabbitMessagePublisher$send$2.callCurrent(Unknown Source)
    at com.budjb.rabbitmq.publisher.RabbitMessagePublisherImpl.send(RabbitMessagePublisherImpl.groovy:93)
    at com.budjb.rabbitmq.publisher.RabbitMessagePublisher$send$1.call(Unknown Source)
    at com.budjb.rabbitmq.consumer.ConsumerContextImpl.deliverMessage(ConsumerContextImpl.groovy:378)
    at com.budjb.rabbitmq.consumer.ConsumerContextImpl.this$2$deliverMessage(ConsumerContextImpl.groovy)
    at com.budjb.rabbitmq.consumer.ConsumerContextImpl$this$2$deliverMessage.call(Unknown Source)
    at com.budjb.rabbitmq.consumer.ConsumerContextImpl$RabbitConsumer.handleDelivery(ConsumerContextImpl.groovy:91)
    at com.rabbitmq.client.impl.ConsumerDispatcher$5.run(ConsumerDispatcher.java:144)
    at com.rabbitmq.client.impl.ConsumerWorkService$WorkPoolRunnable.run(ConsumerWorkService.java:99)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

I also tried to making a converter as given in plugin documentation
http://budjb.github.io/grails-rabbitmq-native/doc/manual/guide/converters.html

but then there is error of no matching constructor found.
Can anybody help me to either how to write converter for image file object or give me some useful solution.

Thanks